# Jmeter remote testing heap size issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

How can I change the heap size of all slave machines while using NON-GUI mode in JMeter distributed test?

Eg: I want to trigger this from the master machine.
C:\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\test.jmx -Jusers=10000 -R192.168.0.19,192.168.0.29......

Is there some parameter that I can pass here so that the heap size of all the slave machines will be changed from the master machine?

Answer (score 0):

1. Heap size is something you set on [JVM startup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html), once it's defined it cannot be controlled
2. JMeter is being launched inside the JVM so first JVM is initialized then it loads [JMeter classes](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

So if you need to control JMeter startup arguments dynamically depending on how you prepare the slaves and your technologies stack you might want to go for something like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [K8S](https://kubernetes.io/), [Docker Swarm](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-with-docker-in-the-cloud), [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), etc.